Slack app not detecting when a message is being sent
I have a slack bot where I want to bridge a slack channel to a discord bot, but the slack part of the app refuses to detect when a message is sent in the specified channel
// Slack
const { App } = require('@slack/bolt');
const { WebClient } = require('@slack/web-api');
const app = new App({
    signingSecret: process.env.SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET,
    token: process.env.SLACK_BOT_TOKEN,
});

const web = new WebClient(process.env.SLACK_BOT_TOKEN);

(async () => {
    await app.start();
    console.log('⚡️ Bolt app is running!');
})();

app.event("message", async ({ message, client, say }) => {
    if(message.channel === "C07B4421B8E"){
        const userInfo = await web.users.info({ user: message.user });

        if (userInfo.ok) {
            console.log("Okay!")
            const username = userInfo.user.name;
            // send a discord message to a certain channel with the contents ect ect
        } else {
            console.log("no, not ok")
        }
        
    } else {
        console.log(message.channel)
    }
})

I've tried searching for a solution, but it seems to be a lot less documented than making discord bots and such
I attempted to change the permissions, but that did not seem to change the outcome.
